# Error: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-142-generic has invalid signature

Tags: boot, grub2

I had Ubuntu Linux installed on my HD and working for several years.  I usually boot the computer every day and turn in off in GUI for the night.  Today, without me changing anything I suddenly see this upon powering up:

`GNU GRUB version 2.04`  (I normally don't see this, I get taken straight to login screen)

`*Ubuntu`

`Advanced options for Ubuntu`

`System setup`

and from here if I hit Enter, or any of the "advanced options", I get

`Error: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-142-generic has invalid signature`
`Error: you need to load the kernel first`

I have not changed *anything* since last proper power-off, I am sure of that.

ASUS Mobo and Bios shows the one hard drive, and two boot options:

`P5 (Ubuntu...`

`Ubuntu...`

Originally I had them in the order above, if I change the order or disable any of them, leads to the same problem.

Does anybody have an idea, is hard-drive bad, can I fix it, or is Linux installation gone bad, can I fix it,  or do I not know how to boot in this new situation that I have not encountered before?

I only have one hard-drive, and on that I only have Ubuntu.  I know how to replace HD and I know how to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, but I would rather not have to do that.

Comment: Try booting an older kernel under advanced.

Comment: @user10489 like I said, same problem

Comment: It should be possible to boot rescue media, possibly including the install disk (use the Try... option) and use that to reinstall a working kernel.   But if this was disk corruption, I would not expect *all* kernels to be corrupted.  I think something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For people who may have such problem in the future:

I fixed the problem (without understanding it of course) by using the "Boot Repair Disk" from https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

I followed instructions and chose "recommended repair" and somehow the problem got fixed.

Comment: This worked after I disabled secure boot from the UEFI boot options.

Comment: @StackUnderflow yea I tried that too, did not work for me. This has to be the best SO name ever, that and "Cadaver".